# Applying custom function on groupby on large data set

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large dataframe (millions of rows) and want to apply a custom function on a groupby.
The dataframe is ordered by "A" as well as a date column "C". The function returns a new vector for "C" which should later replace the original column "C".

This is what I'm doing:

```
result = df.groupby("A", sort=False).apply(lambda x: myFunction(x["B"], x["C"], x["D"])
```

The function itself takes three columns as input arguments, does some order-sensitive if-else calculations and returns "C" with possibly changed values.

```
def myFunction(B, C, D):
    df = pd.concat([B, C, D], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    ... some if-else calculations ...

    return(df["C"])
```

Now this calculation takes many hours if not days to complete on the whole dataset.

Also, `result` is now a dataframe where each row is the result of one groupby-group.
However i would want the result to be one continues vector where the newly returned "C" columns replace the column "C" in the original dataframe.

I'm pretty sure there is a way better way to do this but I can't seem to find it.

The whole thing was originally programmed in R with dplyr and was running way quicker.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(C= myFunction(B,C,D))
```